# Excel needing to find cases where 3 out of 5 numbers in a row are greater than or equal to .45

Tags: excel

Excel needing to find cases where 3 out of 5 numbers in a row are greater than or equal to .45

I have a huge table, needing to find when 3 out of 5 consecutive rows match the >=.45 criteria.  Thanks.

Tried many google searches, Excel documentation, YouTube

Comment: Can you please specify if you meant five consecutive rows or five consecutive columns in one row? Or show an example, that would be even better!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Countif in each row. The following formula counts how many cells in that row have values >= 0.45.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:E2,">=0.45")
```

Then use a helper column to identify consecutive rows with a count of 3.

```
=IF(AND(F2=3,F3=3,F4=3),1,0)
```

Then total that column. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The original post is somewhat confusing - I thought he meant that if three consecutive rows are greater or equal to 0.45, but I see that your solution checks for  five consecutive columns in each row. I was going to post an answer for consecutive rows but I guess I will wait for feedback.

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos  No, my row check just counts the number of cells with values > 0.45. The helper column then checks for three consecutive rows.

Comment: If the question turned out to be looking for 3/5 >=.45 going down a single column, the answer would be almost the same, =COUNTIF(A1:A5,">=0.45")

Comment: @TomSharpe That's exactly the formula I use in column F, as I explain above.  What do you want to improve?

Comment: Your formula is perfect and can't be improved for counting across five columns in a single row. I was wondering if OP meant rather that the data was in a single column and wanted to check for 3 out of 5 values in adjacent cells of that single column being >=.45.